# Is there a one click way to make a kindle fire a pure Android device?

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

For non-technical users, is a one click way to get rid of the amazon stuff & install stock Android?

I am trying to help a friend on another continent who has a kindle fire 7 running OS v 5.6.8 (auto-updated just a few days ago, which looks like it might be a problem).

Solutions seem to involve downloading scripts to a PC, then using Android Studio to side-load the scripts to the kindle, then running them, which would beyond my friend, even with assistance - even if they had a PC, which they do not (nor access to one), just the kindle fire.

Does anyone know of a one-click solution, or something close to it, involving only the kindle fire (7 OS 5.6.8)?

Comment: freeze app from settings. don't know kindle os, so universal way is via package manager. unfortunately that is from cmd line. but you may find some app doing this

Comment: I suppose that I could accept a command line solution, as my friend could copy/paste, as long as it i snot too complicated. Free free to post an answer, if it is simple, although it seems like there maybe complications with the newer OS. However, we can only try.

Comment: can you share links to scripts please? maybe there is a way to run that scripts from tasker https://www.xda-developers.com/tasker-5-9-2-beta-run-adb-shell-commands-without-tethered-pc

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-a-Default-or-Core-System-Apps-from-an-Android-Phone

Comment: that is the universal method from cmd line (adb shell) https://www.xda-developers.com/disable-system-app-bloatware-android

Comment: that is such kind of app, just find some with better reputation ;) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slajedteam.systemappdisabler